# Ruby: wrong element type Symbol at 0 (expected array)

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am wondering why trying to convert this array to a hash causes an error:

```
[:a, [1,2,3]].to_h
=> TypeError: wrong element type Symbol at 0 (expected array)
Hash[ [:a, [1,2,3]] ]
=> ArgumentError: invalid number of elements (3 for 1..2)
```

The array hash two items. So it should be easily converted to a key/value pair, which is what a hash is.

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
 [ [:a, [1,2,3]], [:b, [4,5,6]] ]
```

And I just want to make it an array of hashes:

```
[ [:a, [1,2,3]], [:b, [4,5,6]] ].collect {|collection| Hash[collection] }
=> ArgumentError: invalid number of elements (3 for 1..2)
```

Why cannot it not convert an array of two items into a key/value pair?

I could do something like this:

```
arr.collect {|item| { item[0] => item[1] } }
=> [{:a=>[1, 2, 3]}, {:b=>[4, 5, 6]}]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Wrap it in `[]` once more

You need **an array of pairs**, since one `Hash` can contain many of those, and that feature is reflected in what its constructors accept. A single **pair** is an **array with 2 elements**.

```
Hash[ [:a, [1,2,3]] ]
```

This is a call to `Hash.[]` with **a single pair** `[:a, [1,2,3]]`.
To make it an array of pairs, wrap once more, getting `[[:a, [1,2,3]]]` or

```
Hash[[[:a, [1,2,3]]]
#   ↑↑↑
#   ||\_pair
#   |\_array of pairs
#   \_call to Hash.[]
```

The amount of square brackets here is nauseating.

If your end goal is an array of hashes, each being a single pair, you could use **destructuring in block arguments** like so:

```
[ [:a, [1,2,3]], [:b, [4,5,6]] ].collect {|(a, b)| {a => b} }
```

This is literally the same thing you're suggesting at the end of your question, only without `[]`.

Comment: Your answer seems not to be clear on the distinction between `to_h` and `Hash[]`. It is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

#### This should work

.to_h takes an array of multple key value pairs

```
[ [:a, [1,2,3]], [:b, [4,5,6]] ].to_h
=> {:a=>[1, 2, 3], :b=>[4, 5, 6]}

[ [:a, [1,2,3]] ].to_h
=> {:a=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

Hash[] takes a single key and value

```
Hash[:a, [1,2,3]]
=> {:a=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

---

#### While these won't

.to_h expects each element in the array to be an array with 2 items. Hence if any item in the array is a not an array itself, it gives a type error.

```
[:a, [1,2,3]].to_h
TypeError: wrong element type Symbol at 0 (expected array)
```

Hash[] with a two arrays returns a hash with the first array as the key and the second array as the value, as it's expecting a single key and value.

```
Hash[ [:a, [1,2,3]], [:b, [4,5,6]] ]
=> {[:a, [1, 2, 3]]=>[:b, [4, 5, 6]]}
```

Comment: Your comment "takes a single array of a key and value"  for `Hash[]` is wrong. `Hash[]` does not take a single array of a key and value; the `[]` is the method name itself.